# Why isn't my script doesn't execute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

rfq.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function showUser(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","rfq_list.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload=showUser(str="ALL")>

    <div id="main" style="width:1150px;margin:0 auto;padding:10px;">
    <div id="title" style="width:1150px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;font-size:30px;color:gray;text-shadow:2px 2px #000;font-family:Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;"><h3>RFQ LIST</h3></div>
    <div id="container" style="width:1100px;">
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT rfq FROM procurement GROUP BY rfq ORDER BY rfq");

    $option = '';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
      $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['rfq'].'">'.$row['rfq'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)" style="overflow:scroll;width:100px;">
            <option value="ALL" selected='ALL'>ALL</option>
            <?php echo $option; ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="txtHint">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

rfq_list.php

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" id="" media="print, projection, screen" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("table").tablesorter({debug: true});
            });
            </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){
        var tfrow = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows.length;
        var tbRow=[];
        for (var i=1;i<tfrow;i++) {
            tbRow[i]=document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i];
            tbRow[i].onmouseover = function(){
              this.style.backgroundColor = '#f3f8aa';
            };
            tbRow[i].onmouseout = function() {
              this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
            };
        }
        };
    </script>
    </head>

    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $q = $_GET["q"];
    $where = '';
    if ( $q != 'ALL' ) {
        $where = " WHERE rfq='$q' ";
    }
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("
        SELECT *,SUM(unit_cost*quantity) AS total_amount 
        FROM procurement 
        $where 
        GROUP BY counter ORDER BY rfq
    ");
    echo'<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th title="Item Name">Item Name</th>
                <th title="Item Description">Description</th>
                <th title="Example : Pc, Pcs, Box and Etc.">Unit</th>
                <th title="Item Price">Unit Cost</th>
                <th title="Total Item Quantity">QTY</th>
                <th title="Total Price">Total Amount</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>';
            echo'<tbody>';
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
     echo'<tr>
                <td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['item_description'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['unit'].'</td>
                <td>'.number_format($row['unit_cost'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
                <td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td>
                <td>'.number_format($row['total_amount'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
           </tr>';
            }
        echo "</tbody></table>";

    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
        ?> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

My problem is this code below didn't executing when the page load. But when I direct to rfq_list.php the script below executes. I think the script in rfq.php XMLHttpRequest affects the script in rfq_list.php

Part of rfq_list.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("table").tablesorter({debug: true});
            });
            </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){
        var tfrow = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows.length;
        var tbRow=[];
        for (var i=1;i<tfrow;i++) {
            tbRow[i]=document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i];
            tbRow[i].onmouseover = function(){
              this.style.backgroundColor = '#f3f8aa';
            };
            tbRow[i].onmouseout = function() {
              this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
            };
        }
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Try: <body onload="showUser('ALL')">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the dom in `rfq.php` is created dynamically using a ajax call, so when your window.onload is executed the tab `table` element does not exists in the page causing the script to fail.

The solution is to convert your script to use jQuery and event delegation, ex

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = '#f3f8aa';
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
        }
    }, '#tfhover tr')
})
```

Also your showUser can be rewritten as

```
function showUser(str) {
    var $txtHint = $('#txtHint');
    if (str == "") {
        $txtHint.html('');
        return;
    }
    $txtHint.load('rfq_list.php?q=' + str)
}
```

Comment: @stackpapao see the update instead of your script... also I assume both the pages has table with id `tfhover`

Comment: it doesn't work, and also the script for my table sorting doesn't work too.

Comment: This is the message in my browser console. " The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ http://localhost/app/rfq.php "

Comment: @stackpapao that is not an error message... how are you saying it is not working... whether the table is getting created?

Comment: When I try your script this is the error. ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ http://localhost/app/rfq.php:5

Comment: @stackpapao that means you have not included jQuery library correctly..can you check whether the file exists at the correct location

Comment: @stackpapao also what is there in that line mentioned in the error

Comment: The file exist in the correct location, I add the jQuery library and the script for table sorting is already working, but the script for mouse over td didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work too, if it is an error? TypeError: $(...).on is not a function @ http://localhost/app/javascript/jquery.js:11

Comment: @stackpapao what is the jQuery version used? is it < 1.7

Comment: jQuery v1.8.2 jquery.com

Comment: @stackpapao what was the problem

Comment: jQuery(function ($) { I changed it into $(function(){ :D

Comment: can I ask just one more question?

Comment: base on my query, how do I select only rfq that has a value. $result1 = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT rfq, item_name, item_description, unit, unit_cost, quantity, SUM(unit_cost*quantity) AS total_amount 
    FROM procurement 
    $where 
    GROUP BY counter ORDER BY rfq
");

what I want is select all rfq that has a value. If $row['rfq']= ' '; don't select? Just like that

Comment: sir are you there? Just want to ask something, with the same question.

Comment: not the PHP question, I'm having a trouble again with the same page. I used fancybox in my script but the same problem comes out. The sorting jquery doesn't execute. Can I send you the code?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        helpers   : { 
  overlay : {
  closeClick: false}
  // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox
  },
  closeClick  : false, // prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox
  scrolling     : 'no',
  width         : 550,
  height        : 0,
  autoScale  : true,
  openEffect   : 'elastic',
  closeEffect  : 'fade',
  closeBtn : true,
  
   afterClose:function () {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    }).trigger("onclick");

});
parent.$.fancybox.close();

Comment: I merged it in my code, but when it runs the same problems comes out. What is the problem with this?

Comment: @stackpapao can you ask it as a separate question?

Comment: this is my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176110/how-to-open-a-page-inside-of-shadowbox