# How to open a page inside of shadowbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a new page inside of shadowbox, when I click the code
this link Opens a new page inside the shadowbox in the same page. How to do that?

```
<a class="fancybox" href="edit.php?pn"></a>
```

rfq_list.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" id="" media="print, projection, screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.2" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                type: "iframe",
                helpers   : { 
          overlay : {
          closeClick: false}
          // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox
          },
          closeClick  : false, // prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox
          scrolling     : 'no',
          width         : 550,
          height        : 0,
          autoScale     : true,
          openEffect    : 'elastic',
          closeEffect   : 'fade',
          closeBtn : true,

                 afterClose:function () {
                window.location.reload();
            }
            }).trigger("onclick");

        });
        parent.$.fancybox.close();
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
            box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
        }
        </style>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $("table").tablesorter({debug: true});
                });
                </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
            var tfrow = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows.length;
            var tbRow=[];
            for (var i=1;i<tfrow;i++) {
                tbRow[i]=document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i];
                tbRow[i].onmouseover = function(){
                  this.style.backgroundColor = '#f3f8aa';
                };
                tbRow[i].onmouseout = function() {
                  this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
                };
            }
            });
        </script>
        </head>
```

rfq.php

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    var $txtHint = $('#txtHint');
    if (str == "") {
        $txtHint.html('');
        return;
    }
    $txtHint.load('rfq_list.php?q=' + str)
}
</script>


<div id="txtHint">
</div>
```

What is the problem in this scripts?

Comment: did you get any error in the console?

Comment: the part of your database queries is totally unimportant for this question. you should try running fancy box on a blank page to see how it works. also check the demos.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function @ http://localhost/app/javascript/jquery.js:4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including jQuery three times:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

and aside particular cases you have to include it once (and use noconflict).

Now the the table sorter plugin will be detached from jQuery by the third include and you face your error.

Remove the other jQuery include and use only the latest.